# ptrace() on iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

Is there an equivalent to ptrace() for iOS?

I'm interested in writing a cheating app.  Basically one that scans the memory of another process and can change it's memory.

(Please refrain from posting comments that question or discourage writing this kind of application.)

Comment: Have you actually tried using `ptrace` ? Because I don't get a linking error when I just call `ptrace()`...

Comment: I think you could get some problems with that aproach, because the iOS is made in a way you can only operate in a sandbox...

Comment: You have no access to the memory of another process in iOS.

Comment: ^ What he said. Memory protection exists for this exact reason!

Comment: Yea, you are all right.  I can add in the contents of /usr/include/sys/ptrace.h myself, and the program will link and run.  Attach and detach work, PT_CONTINUE returns 'Operation not supported' and PT_READ_U returns 'Invalid argument'.

Comment: you should use vm_read_write to read and write data.but pt_continue returns 'Operation not supported' for me too.